# route url to external rest conroller using apache camel

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, apache-camel

Is there any way to route all request to specific URI to another projects rest controller?
consider the code below:

```
    @Component
public class CamelSportsRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration()
                .component("servlet")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

        rest().path("/hello").get().route()
                .toD("localhost:9080/hello");
}
}
```

I want to route all request of `/hello`  to another project rest controller endpoint: `localhost:9080/hello` but without XML it cant be possible.

Answer (score 0):

See matchOnUriPrefix of jetty and undertown components and bridgeEndpoint option of HTTP component.

This is what you need:

```java
from("undertow:http://localhost:8080/hello?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
.to("http4://localhost:8081/hello?bridgeEndpoint=true");
```

Also see this another answer to more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/67893371/11052487