# Apache camel route a URI to another URI

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, restlet, http4s

Is it possible to route all of request to another server directly? For example route all of this project specific rest endpoint localhost:8080/get-something to another project endpoint like this: someIp:8081/get-something2 . something like this:

```
from("localhost:8080/get-something")
.to("someIp:8081/get-something2")
```

or this:

```
rest()
            .path("/get-something")
            .get()
                .route()
.to("someIp:8081/get-something2")
```

I've tried too many ways but I cant!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a WireTap, just going by your description.

So you’ll do something like

’’’
from("localhost:8080/get-something")
. wiretap(“direct:endpoint1”) // will receive exchange
. wiretap(“direct:endpoint2”) // will receive exchange
.to(ACTUAL_DESTINATION); // will receive exchange
…
;

’’’

Then

’’’
from(“direct:endpoint1”)
.to(MY_SERVER1);

from(“direct:endpoint2”)
.to(MY_SERVER2);
’’’

Something to note though, is that these are completely separate messages (think a carbon copy) **only if you specify a custom processor via the onPrepareRef property**

Comment: Your answer should be readable. Please use proper options while write your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a http based component (jetty or undertow) as consumer (from) with `matchOnUriPrefix=true` option and then send it to an http component using `bridgeEndpoint=true` option.

Example:

```java
from("undertow:http://localhost:8080/?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
.to("http4://google.com/?bridgeEndpoint=true");
```

That way any request sent to localhost:8080/ will be forwarded to google.com/

Try http://localhost:8080/ in your browser and you will get google web page.

Try http://localhost:8080/search?q=camel in your browser and you will get response for "camel" search.

In your case you could do:

```java
from("undertow:http://localhost:8080/?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
.to("http4://localhost:8081/?bridgeEndpoint=true");
```

Docs:

- https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/http-component.html
- https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/undertow-component.html
- https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-do-i-let-jetty-match-wildcards.html